# Directory.Delete with recursion randomly fails, saying "Directory not empty"

Tags: c#, exception

I have a staging directory that I want to clean up if it was used during my script.  The code is simple:

```
if (Directory.Exists(_stagingDir) &&
    Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(_stagingDir).Any())
{
    Directory.Delete(_stagingDir, true);
}
```

Sometimes, it fails with an IO Exception that the "Directory is not empty."  Shouldn't that not matter if I'm recursively deleting all the items inside (which is what `true` should do in that function)?  If I back the script up a few lines and run it again, it works fine.

My only guess is that the `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` is locking a file, but I would have guessed I'd get a much different exception ("access denied" or "file locked" or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother calling `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` at all? If that's the cause of your problem, then just simplify to:

```
if (Directory.Exists(_stagingDir))
{
    Directory.Delete(_stagingDir, true);
}
```

I suspect that the reason you're getting this error is that the enumeration returned by `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` is not getting disposed by the time that you call `Delete()`, meaning that its handles to the filesystem entries are still open. You *could* rewrite this with `using` to get around the problem, but really you're better off removing the superfluous call altogether as shown above.

Comment: Duh ... not sure why that didn't occur to me.  Thanks!